# jQuery basic animations issue

Tags: jquery, html

this is my first post here, first of all sorry for my English.

I've been searching my issue for sometime but I didn't find anything about it. Maybe it's a silly question and maybe it has an easy answer, but I can't see it.

I'm learning javascript and jquery, I know some html and css, this time I wanted to try the event binding in query.

I created buttons and divs and I wanted the divs to slide when I pushed a certain button using slideToggle.

But when I push the first button, the first div slides up (as predicted) but then it slides down without me pulsing the button, the last div dissapears at the same time. I'm a noob and I'd appreciate any help with this, thanks :)

You can watch the image to have a look to the code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/orRPw.png

Comment: Instead of posting link to an image, you'd have better to post relevant code in question, just saying

Comment: It is a good practice to paste your code into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), and include both your code formatted, plus the link to your JSFiddle. Also, try to sort your question's text into blocks, so it is easier to read.

Comment: Is there any reason you're setting the HTML of the buttons with Jquery? Are you trying to change their text dynamically when you click the buttons?

Comment: Sorry about this, I didn't know JSFiddle, it seems very cool, I'll be using it  from now to post here, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is completely different from what you want to accomplish.

---

What you are currently doing:

`$('.button1').html('<p>button 1</p>');` will set the HTML of `.button1` to 'button 1'. This code snippet does *not* interact with the events you desire in any way. All it does is setting the text of the given `button` in this case.

`$('div:first').slideToggle();` will `slideToggle()` the *first* div. jQuery uses CSS selectors for getting DOM elements. `div:first` is the very first div on your HTML page.

---

What you want instead is assigning each `button` to its `div` through specific event handlers.

#### Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.button1').on('click', function () {
        $('.div1').slideToggle();
    });

    $('.button2').on('click', function () {
        $('.div2').slideToggle();
    });

    $('.button3').on('click', function () {
        $('.div3').slideToggle();
    });

    $('.button4').on('click', function () {
        $('.div4').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/42knLk1n/

Comment: Thanks for your help!! You were right, I wasn't doing it correctly, only changing the style tag to show display:none would fit but it's better your way. Thanks again :)

Comment: It's my pleasure. If you decide this is the answer you were looking for, please don't hesitate to mark it as such. It benefits everyone.